# Splitwise API login issue

Tags: java, rest, api

Hi when I'm using splitwise  API using

```
GET URL(https://www.splitwise.com/api/v3.0/get_current_user)
```

to login I'm getting following error:

```
{"error":"Invalid API Request: you are not logged in"}
```

Please help

Comment: The message clearly says the you are not logged in. You have to first Login to Spliwise account and then may be based on some authorization token, you will be able to query the API. Once Token validity over, you will have to login again. Please check their website and required parameter for making the request. Check their API as well - https://github.com/sritejakv/splitwise-java

Comment: Thanks Swaraj for the reply.Yes I need to login first but I don't see any API to login in their documentation.then without login how can I see the token generated

Answer (score 0):

Here is the authentication API details - https://dev.splitwise.com/?javascript#authentication

Comment: I've seen that code but how can i use that code to do login using postman(REST API)

Comment: Explained here. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/

Comment: thanks for the response. i've gone through the documentation then splitwise is asking to register my app for oath authorization but i don't have any app to register just my goal is automating splitwise expenses using REST API calls.